# Regex Statement for Dynatrace request naming rules

Tags: regex, dynatrace

I am trying to form a regex expression that I would like to use in Dynatrace Request naming rules so it can name the requests that's matching this Regex on a more friendly name and I am having a hard time framing one that suits my needs . The tool only supports "Contains Regex" and "Does not contain Regex" operators which is leading me to match multiple items I dont wish to match .

Example Regex Statement (I use this with  "Contains Regex" operator)

`/getdata/[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}`

Request that I would only like to match :

`/getdata/0209133c-6beb-45f4-a9c8-063d86d53609`

Other requests that the same regex is matching :

```
/getdata/0209133c-6beb-45f4-a9c8-063d86d53609/confirm
/getdata/0209133c-6beb-45f4-a9c8-063d86d53609/order/cancel
/getdata/0209133c-6beb-45f4-a9c8-063d86d53609/retry
```

I understand why its matching it , its basically doing what its asked to do , but I am looking to understand if there is any way to specify what I want using the Contains Regex operator.

Comment: Does your tool support `$` as end of line in regexes?

Answer (score 1):

The `$` end-of-line [anchor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) was designed to help you
with exactly this problem.
(I will also use the `^` start-of-line anchor as a Best Practice,
since it allows us to [efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) skip lines that don't match.)

```
^/getdata/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$
```

Almost equivalently we could write a similar regex:

```
^/getdata/[0-9a-f-]{36}$
```

Comment: Thank you so much , the $ seem like its doing the trick . This is surely more efficient that the work around I came up with of using a match and an not match :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out in couple of mins after I read my own questions .

So I ended up using -

Matches - `/getdata/[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}`

Not Matches - `/getdata/[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}/`

Please someone let me know if there is any other efficient way of handling the same in a single regex statement :)